# Android: "I want to end My countDownTimer with 0th position"

Tags: android

In this code, it is not finishing at 0th position, but at 0th position, it has still 1 more min remaining and I want to finish at 0th position only.

```
case 0:
    new CountDownTimer(60000 * 5, 60000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {

            textView.setText("Time Left: "+ (millisUntilFinished/60000));
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {

            textView.setText("Time Finished");
        }
    }.start();
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 more second to your Timer:

```
                new CountDownTimer(60000 * 6, 60000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
                    {

                        textView.setText("Time Left: "+ ((millisUntilFinished/60000)-1));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish()
                    {

                        textView.setText("Time Finished");
                    }
                }.start();
```

Comment: No it zero position it still 1 min Remaining.I want to call **onFinish()** method when my **CountDownTimer** come to zero position

Comment: Did you minus by 1 in `onTick`?

Comment: Yes I did but not solved, actually at last one minutes it wait for 2 minutes but on textview  it show me 1 minutes